# Trigonometric equation $\sin2x=\cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> What is the number of solutions to 
>   $$\sin2x=\cos x$$
>   on the interval $[0,3\pi]$

What I tried here is:

$\sin2x=\cos x\\2\sin x\cos x=\cos x$

dividing this by $2\cos x$ I get

$\sin x={1\over2}$

And from here I know

$x={\pi\over6}+2k\pi$

And looking in the interval I can only find 2 solutions, $x\in\{{\pi\over6},{25\pi\over6}\}$

But looking at the results, there should be 7 results, what  am I missing? And what should I do to get these results

Comment: Hint: In what situation can you not divide by $2\cos(x)$?

Comment: Don't divide, factor! Write it as $\cos(x)[2\sin(x)-1] = 0$ and use that if $ab=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: Also, you appear to be missing a solution to $\sin(x) = 1/2$.

Comment: Thanks on the hints, got it now! I've got 7 results as said. Weird that I missed something that obvious!

Comment: @Aleksa: it is a common mistake to transform an equation and forget under what conditions the transformation preserves the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nicholas Stull hinted, you lost solutions by not making sure that you were not dividing by zero.  As @Winther pointed out, you can avoid this error by factoring.  As @Nicholas Stull pointed out, you also overlooked some of the solutions of the equation $\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$.  Also, 
$$\frac{25\pi}{6} > \frac{18\pi}{6} = 3\pi$$
so $\frac{25\pi}{6}$ is not a valid solution.

Here is a different approach that should make it less tempting to divide.  You can prove that 
$$\cos x = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)$$
by using the angle difference formula for sine
$$\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta$$
Therefore,
$$\sin(2x) = \cos x$$
is equivalent to
$$\sin(2x) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)$$
When does $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$?

Consider the figure below:

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Two directed angles have the same sine if the points where their terminal sides intersect the unit circle have the same $y$-coordinate, which occurs if $\varphi = \theta$ or $\varphi = \pi - \theta$.  It also occurs if $\varphi$ is coterminal with $\theta$ or $\pi - \theta$.  Hence, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
At the risk of obscuring the symmetry argument, you could write that $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = (-1)^n\theta + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
With that in mind, let's solve the equation.
\begin{align*}
\sin(2x) & = \cos x\\
\sin(2x) & = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)
\end{align*}
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
2x & = \frac{\pi}{2} - x + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} & 2x & = \pi - \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
3x & = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} & 2x & = \pi - \frac{\pi}{2} + x + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x & = \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{2k\pi}{3}, k \in \mathbb{Z} &  x & = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
We want solutions in the interval $[0, 3\pi]$.  As you should verify, we obtain a solution in this interval if $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ or $m = 0, 1$.  Since these seven solutions are distinct, the equation $\sin(2x) = \cos x$ has seven solutions in this interval.